# Why does this Flutter test fails on CodeMagic?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, codemagic

When I try to test the build on Codemagic, the test fails. I tried to change widget_test.dart code, Still the problem remains unsolved. How to resolve this issue?

This is the error thrown by codemagic.

```
== QA ==

== flutter test --machine ==
{"protocolVersion":"0.1.1","runnerVersion":null,"pid":949,"type":"start","time":0}
{"suite":{"id":0,"platform":"vm","path":"/Users/builder/clone/test/widget_test.dart"},"type":"suite","time":1}
{"test":{"id":1,"name":"loading /Users/builder/clone/test/widget_test.dart","suiteID":0,"groupIDs":[],"metadata":{"skip":false,"skipReason":null},"line":null,"column":null,"url":null},"type":"testStart","time":3}
{"count":1,"type":"allSuites","time":7}
{"testID":1,"result":"success","skipped":false,"hidden":true,"type":"testDone","time":15317}
{"group":{"id":2,"suiteID":0,"parentID":null,"name":null,"metadata":{"skip":false,"skipReason":null},"testCount":1,"line":null,"column":null,"url":null},"type":"group","time":15341}
{"test":{"id":3,"name":"Counter increments smoke test","suiteID":0,"groupIDs":[2],"metadata":{"skip":false,"skipReason":null},"line":107,"column":3,"url":"package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart","root_line":14,"root_column":3,"root_url":"file:///Users/builder/clone/test/widget_test.dart"},"type":"testStart","time":15343}
{"testID":3,"messageType":"print","message":"══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════\nThe following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:\n  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree\n  Actual: ?:<zero widgets with text \"0\" (ignoring offstage widgets)>\n   Which: means none were found but one was expected\n\nWhen the exception was thrown, this was the stack:\n#4      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/builder/clone/test/widget_test.dart:19:5)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#5      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:118:25)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#6      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:630:19)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#9      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:613:14)\n#10     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1010:24)\n#16     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1007:15)\n#17     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:116:22)\n#18     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#19     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:250:15)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#24     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:247:5)\n#25     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:166:33)\n#30     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:165:13)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#31     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:400:25)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#45     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)\n#46     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)\n#47     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)\n(elided 28 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)\n\nThis was caught by the test expectation on the following line:\n  file:///Users/builder/clone/test/widget_test.dart line 19\nThe test description was:\n  Counter increments smoke test\n════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════","type":"print","time":17092}
{"testID":3,"error":"Test failed. See exception logs above.\nThe test description was: Counter increments smoke test","stackTrace":"","isFailure":false,"type":"error","time":17119}
{"testID":3,"result":"error","skipped":false,"hidden":false,"type":"testDone","time":17134}
{"success":false,"type":"done","time":17231}


QA failed :|
Flutter test run failed.

== QA failed, ending build ==


Build failed :|
Test run failed: Flutter test run failed.
```

My Widget_test file code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:top100/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Comment: But this test passes in your local, right?

Comment: If you mean by running it on my phone, yeah i can!

Comment: execute `flutter test`  That test is generated with the `flutter create` template. It will only work if you still have the counter app. If that is not case, remove the test :)

Comment: I deleted the folder, once I created the project. I didn't knew it was important. Is there any way to overcome this issue? Because I almost completed a new application but I can't test it in Codemagic. I tried removing the 'test' directory, it didn't work obviously.

Comment: Hi @GokulaKrishnan, were you able to fix your tests?

Comment: Yeah. Well not exactly. I deleted the whole test folder and ran the CI/CD without flutter test. So yeah it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the test folder and ran it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The widget_test.dart file is created with the default project in Flutter, which has  two text fields and an Icon which can be tapped. Since you modified the app UI, now you may have different elements showing and the test fails since it is expecting the template project elements which now you don't have. You can comment the `testWidgets` method for a quick fix:

```
// This is a basic Flutter widget test.
//
// To perform an interaction with a widget in your test, use the WidgetTester
// utility that Flutter provides. For example, you can send tap and scroll
// gestures. You can also use WidgetTester to find child widgets in the widget
// tree, read text, and verify that the values of widget properties are correct.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:fin_app_flutter/main.dart';

void main() {
  /*
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    // Verify that our counter starts at 0.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);

    // Tap the '+' icon and trigger a frame.
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
    await tester.pump();

    // Verify that our counter has incremented.
    expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
  */
}
```

Remember to commit and sync your branch on Codemagic.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Codemagic is trying to run integration tests which you probably don't have. Please note that integration tests are different from unit tests or widget tests. Integration tests are run by Flutter Driver, [read more](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction).

Integration tests are also called "Flutter Driver tests". If you do `flutter drive`, Flutter runs all the integration tests in your project. Here's a snippet from the help command:

[image: Screenshot from 2020-09-06 15-58-07]

With that said, the reason you're getting that error is because you don't have any integration tests in your project. All you have to do is disable integration tests in your Codemagic workflow:

[image]